# Find mirror image of an point

Tags: geometry

I have a homework assignment that I have solved but don't know if its correct.

The assignment is to find the mirror image of the point $(3,4)$ on the line $y = 2x + 1$. I call the mirror image Q(a,b)

To solve this I did the following steps.

Step 1 calculate the slope of the second line

$k_1 \cdot k_2 = -1$ => $2 \cdot k_2 = -1$ => $k_2 = - \frac{1}{2}$

Step 2

$k = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$ => $- \frac{1}{2} = \frac{b - 4}{a - 3}$

$- \frac{1}{2}(a-3) = b-4$ => $b = - \frac{1}{2}a + 5.5$

Step 3

m( $\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}$, $\frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}$) => m( $\frac{a + 3}{2}$, $\frac{b + 4}{2}$)

$\frac{b + 4}{2} = 2 \cdot  \frac{a + 3}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$ => $b = 2a +1$

Step 4

$\begin{cases}b = - \frac{1}{2}a + 5.5  \\  b = 2a +1 \end{cases}$

Step five solve equation above, this leads to $a = 1.8$. Then plug in $a$ to any of the two equation and $b = 4.6$

Is this the correct answer?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you write $\frac{b + 4}{2} = 2 \cdot  \frac{a + 3}{2} +1$ ?

Comment: The point $(1.8, 4.6)$ is on the line $y=2x+1$.  So it's not the reflection of $(3,4)$ across the line (since $(3,4)$ is not on the line).

Comment: I am saying that the midpoint of the segment $[(3,4),(a,b)]$ must stay on the line $y=2x+1$ . Surely the second equation is wrong because it means that $(a,b)$ is on $y=2x+1$.

Comment: ok, So whats the formula to find the reflection on (3,4)?

Comment: Couple the equation in my first comment with your first equation and solve the system.